# Crear SELECT dinámico con javascript con array asociativo en vez de normal SIN eval()

Tags: javascript, mysql, php7, select, mariadb

¡Hola!

Quisiera hacer una serie de `SELECT` dinánicos, cuyo contenido cuyo contenido depende de los `SELECT` anteriores. La única forma que he encontrado usa la función `eval()` pero por lo visto no es una buena opción usar esa función.

Además, yo quisiera hacerlo con un array asociativo en vez de un array normal, porque así, al crearlo, al valor del `option` le añadiría la clave y como texto del `option` le pondría el valor de dicha clave. Eemplo:

```html
<select name="ComunidadAutonomaEnvio" id="ComunidadAutonomaEnvio">
    <option value="Selecciona">- Selecciona -</option>
    <option value="Andalucia">Andalucía</option>
    <option value="LaRioja">La Rioja</option>
</select>
```

Con un array asociativo, como por  ejemplo:

```
var comunidadesAutonomas = {
    "Andalucia" : "Andalucía",
    "LaRioja" : "La Rioja"
};
```

También me gustaría seleccionar la opción concreta guardada previamente en la base de datos  mysql(en  concreto, por si influye, mariadb). Si bien en el formulario normal la  primera opción estará seleccionada por defecto, quisiera saber cómo decidir dinámicamente (según el dato obtenido con PHP desde MYSQL mediante un objeto como `$direccion->getComunidadAutonoma()` ) un index concreto buscándolo por el texto del option(el valor en el array) o por el valor del option(la clave del array).

¡Gracias!

Comment: hay un attibuto que se llama `selected` que se utiliza para elegir una opcion dentro del select ejemplo: `<option value="Selecciona" selected>- Selecciona -</option>` ahora solo bastaria compara tu `$direccion->getComunidadAutonoma()` con el valor del option

Comment: ¡Estupendo! ¡Muchas gracias! ¿Sería similar aesto? `if(ComunidadAutonomaEnvio.options.[comunidadAutonomaEnvio.selectedIndex].text == <?php echo $direccion->getComunidadAutonoma() ?>){ComunidadAutonomaEnvio.options.[comunidadAutonomaEnvio.selectedIndex].selected }`